# store data by click on selected div in reactjs

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-state

I have a data that map on my div I want to change state(useing useState) by click and store data of selected div
this is my component that show data

```js
export const data = [
  { symbol: 'ddd', stockNum: '2700', EPS: '234', PE: '11.2', iid: 'IRO3SAIZ0001' },
  { symbol: 'ggg', stockNum: '2700', EPS: '258', PE: '11.2', iid: '71483646978964608' },
  { symbol: 'ttt', stockNum: '2700', EPS: '266', PE: '11.2', iid: '46348559193224090' },
  { symbol: 'qq', stockNum: '2700', EPS: '211', PE: '11.2', iid: '10' },
  { symbol: 'iii', stockNum: '2700', EPS: '222', PE: '11.2', iid: '90' },
];

<div className="d-flex">
            {data && data.length > 0
              ? data.map((item, index) => {
                  return (
                    <>
                      <div className="box-stock" onClick={() => selectStockAction(item)}>
                        <div className="top-stock skewed p-5" s>
                          <h1>{item.symbol}</h1>
                          <strong className="text-center" >
                            <span > (0.25)</span>
                            {item.stockNum}
                          </strong>
                          <Label className="text-center">
                            EPS:<span className="text-white">{item.EPS}</span>
                          </Label>
                          <Label className="text-center">
                            P/E:<span className="text-white">{item.PE}</span>
                          </Label>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </>
                  );
                })
              : 'no data'}
          </div>
```

Comment: create another state to store selectedData on, and invoke your function to set the state ?

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this

```
  export const data = [
  {
    symbol: "ddd",
    stockNum: "2700",
    EPS: "234",
    PE: "11.2",
    iid: "IRO3SAIZ0001",
  },
  {
    symbol: "ggg",
    stockNum: "2700",
    EPS: "258",
    PE: "11.2",
    iid: "71483646978964608",
  },
  {
    symbol: "ttt",
    stockNum: "2700",
    EPS: "266",
    PE: "11.2",
    iid: "46348559193224090",
  },
  { symbol: "qq", stockNum: "2700", EPS: "211", PE: "11.2", iid: "10" },
  { symbol: "iii", stockNum: "2700", EPS: "222", PE: "11.2", iid: "90" },
];

const Test = () => {
  const [selectStockAction, setSelectStockAction] = useState();

  return (
    <>
      <div className="d-flex">
        {data && data.length > 0
          ? data.map((item, index) => {
              return (
                <React.Fragment key={index}>
                  <div
                    className="box-stock"
                    onClick={() => setSelectStockAction(item)}
                  >
                    <div className="top-stock skewed p-5">
                      <h1>{item.symbol}</h1>
                      <strong className="text-center">
                        <span> (0.25)</span>
                        {item.stockNum}
                      </strong>
                      <Label className="text-center">
                        EPS:<span className="text-white">{item.EPS}</span>
                      </Label>
                      <Label className="text-center">
                        P/E:<span className="text-white">{item.PE}</span>
                      </Label>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </React.Fragment>
              );
            })
          : "no data"}
      </div>

      <div>
        <Label className="text-center">Selected Stock Action</Label>
        <div className="top-stock skewed p-5">
          <h1>{`Selected Stock Action ${
            selectStockAction?.symbol ? selectStockAction?.symbol : ""
          }`}</h1>
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
};
```